# Use Identifier before Defining for BNF-Style Definitions

Tags: coq

In defining a BNF grammar it's common to use things before defining them so that the grammar reads "forwards."

How can one do this in coq and still be able to step through buffers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Coq, the notion of *buffer* is not pre-defined, so it is quite hard to understand what you mean.  Still there are two aspects of Coq that give a feeling of possible look-ahead, and which could be used when defining a BNF grammar.

- Recursive function definitions can introduce simultaneously several recursive functions.
- Type definitions can introduce simultaneously several inductive types.

In both cases, the first object being defined can refer to the second one before it is defined.

Here are two examples, the first one is about recursive functions.

```
Fixpoint even (n : nat) : bool :=
   match n with
     0 => true
   | S p => negb( odd p)
   end
with odd (n : nat) : bool :=
  match n with
    0 => false
  | S p => negb (even p)
  end.
```

You see in this example that the function `even` refers to the function `odd` before it is defined.

Now comes the second example.  I try to stick to your leading metaphor of BNF.  A grammar description can be given as an inductive predicate.  Here is a small example with a grammar for arithmetic expressions involving only addition, multiplication, and natural numbers.

```
Require Import String Ascii Arith.

Definition digit (c : ascii) : bool :=
  (nat_of_ascii "0" <=? nat_of_ascii c) &&
  (nat_of_ascii c <=? nat_of_ascii "9").

Fixpoint number (s : string) : bool :=
  match s with
  | String c EmptyString => digit c
  | String c tl => digit c && number tl
  | EmptyString => false
  end.

Inductive Exp1 : string -> Prop :=
  plus : forall x y, Exp2 x -> Exp1 y -> Exp1 (x ++ "+" ++ y)
| inj2 : forall x, Exp2 x -> Exp1 x
with
  Exp2 : string -> Prop :=
  times : forall x y, Exp3 x -> Exp2 y -> Exp2 (x ++ "*" ++ y)
| inj3 : forall x, Exp3 x -> Exp2 x
with
  Exp3 : string -> Prop :=
|  num : forall x, number x = true -> Exp3 x
|  inj1 : forall x, Exp1 x -> Exp3 ("(" ++ x ++ ")").
```

With this description of a grammar, I can prove that a given expression respects the grammar.

```
Lemma example : Exp1 "3+2*(5*4)".
Proof.
apply (plus "3" "2*(5*4)").
  apply inj3.
  apply num; reflexivity.
apply inj2.
apply (times "2" "(5*4)").
  apply num; reflexivity.
apply inj3, (inj1 "5*4"), inj2, (times "5" "4").
  apply num; reflexivity.
apply inj3, num; reflexivity.
Qed.
```

This does not describe a parser. This would be another exercise.

Your question is so terse that I don't even know whether this is an answer.

Comment: Exactly, yes. I didn't realize the ML "with" style would work with inductive definitions... This makes for a somewhat messy situation for documentation (since most of the grammar will need to be written in a single definition) but this gives me what I need.

Comment: If you want to write a grammar in several steps, you may still take advantage of higher-order capabilities of the specification language.